# Пересобрать массив PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет! Есть массив `foreach($products as $ val) {}`:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 31
        [quantity] => 5
        [price] => $100.00
        [total] => $500.00
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 47
        [quantity] => 2
        [price] => $200.00
        [total] => $400.00
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 47
        [quantity] => 2
        [price] => $200.00
        [total] => $400.00
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 47
        [quantity] => 2
        [price] => $200.00
        [total] => $400.00
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 50
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => $300.00
        [total] => $300.00
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 50
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => $300.00
        [total] => $300.00
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 50
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => $300.00
        [total] => $300.00
    )
```

)

Как посчитать сумму `quantuty`, если совпадает `product_id`, после `unset` удалить дубли по `product_id`

Результат должен иметь вид:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
(
    [product_id] => 31
    [quantity] => 5
    [price] => $100.00
    [total] => $500.00
)
[1] => Array
(
    [product_id] => 47
    [quantity] => 6
    [price] => $200.00
    [total] => $1200.00
)
[2] => Array
(
    [product_id] => 50
    [quantity] => 3
    [price] => $300.00
    [total] => $900.00
)
```

Comment: добавил в вопрос: foreach($products as $ val) { ... }

Comment: из коробки opancart2.2 - ee трогать нельзя, надо в контроллере пересобрать

Comment: Я тут подумал. А давайте закроем этот оффтопик "ну-ка напишите мне код по-быстрому"?

Comment: я тоже пишу......не хочешь помогать не помогай, мы уже как-то мне помниться на одном вопросе пересекались....

Comment: @Ипатьев Уважаемый, на принципе вопрос-ответ строиться политика сайта, а Вы вместо того чтоб спам разводить лучше бы сами ответ написала, если конечно клепа хватит. Будьте взаимно вежливы Господа!)

Comment: а array_unique($products,SORT_REGULAR) проверяли?

Comment: да. массив остается без изменений, т.к. не все значения дублируются

Comment: Всем большое спасибо!) Немного под себя доработал - все получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$new_arr=array(); 
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        $product_id=$value['product_id'];
        $quantity=$value['quantity'];
        $price=$value['price'];
        if (array_key_exists($product_id, $new_arr)) {
            $new_quantity=$new_arr[$product_id]['quantity']+$quantity;
            $new_arr[$product_id]['quantity']=$new_quantity;
            $new_arr[$product_id]['total']=$new_quantity*$price;
        } else {
            $new_arr[$product_id]['quantity']=$quantity;
            $new_arr[$product_id]['price']=$price;
            $new_arr[$product_id]['total']=$quantity*$price;
        }
}
```

Изначально следовало бы ключами массива делать не номер по порядку, а уникальный ИД товара. Ушло бы много мороки. А валюту следует хранить отдельно ($200*2 не посчитает).

Дополнил на основе комментариев

```
    $products=Array(
        '0' => Array
            (
                'product_id' => '47',
                'quantity' => '5',
                'price' => '200.00',
                'total' => '1000.00',
                'thumb' => 'thumb.00',
                'name' => 'name.00',
                'model' => 'model.00',
                'size' => '34'
            ),
        '1' => Array
            (
                'product_id' => '47',
                'quantity' => '2',
                'price' => '200.00',
                'total' => '400.00',
                'thumb' => 'thumb.00',
                'name' => 'name.00',
                'model' => 'model.00',
                'size' => '56'
            )
        );

    $new_arr=array();

    $balast_values_names=array(1 => 'thumb', 2 => 'name', 3 => 'model'); // тут все статичные переменные

foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    $product_id=$value['product_id'];
    $quantity=$value['quantity'];
    $price=$value['price'];
    /*
        Играем на свойстве ключей массивов - может быть только один уникальный ключ. И в качестве ключа берём product_id.
        Перебираем циклом (немного выше мы уже начали перебор) все значения исходного массива. И формируем новый.
        Ключами нового массива будет product_id исходного. Таким образом, если встретим в исходном массиве два товара с одним product_id,
        то более новый перезапишет более старый в новом массиве. А нам нужно сохранить все данные. Особеннно количество товаров.
        Потому array_key_exists($product_id, $new_arr) проверяет, есть ли у нас в новом массиве уже значение ключа равное product_id из исходого массива
        Если есть, до дополняем в новом массиве его дополнительными данными из старого (добавляем количество заказов, пересчитываем стоимость и т.п.)
        Если нет, то просто добавляем все данные
    */
    if (array_key_exists($product_id, $new_arr)) {
        $new_quantity=$new_arr[$product_id]['quantity']+$quantity;
        $new_arr[$product_id]['quantity']=$new_quantity;
        $new_arr[$product_id]['total']=$new_quantity*$price;

        //это код для размеров обуви (если от размера не зависит цена)
        $want_to_add_in_array_size=$value['size'];
        //тут смотрим, если размер обуви, который хотим добавить не совпадает с теми, что уже есть в новом массиве, то добавляем его. А если совпадает, то ничего не делаем
        if (!in_array($want_to_add_in_array_size, $new_arr[$product_id]['size'])) { 
            $new_arr[$product_id]['size'][]=$want_to_add_in_array_size;
        }
    } else {
        $new_arr[$product_id]['quantity']=$quantity;
        $new_arr[$product_id]['price']=$price;
        $new_arr[$product_id]['total']=$quantity*$price;

        //если каждый ИД товара - уникальная единица, то (размеры предусмотрены ниже)
        //переносим все значения статичным переменных
        foreach ($balast_values_names as $key2 => $balast) {
            $new_arr[$product_id][$balast]=$value[$balast];
        }

        //размеры загоняем сюда (если от размера не зависит стоимость, конечно)
        $new_arr[$product_id]['size'][]=$value['size'];
    }
}

    print_r($products);
    echo '<br><br><br>';
    print_r($new_arr);
```

В результате получим

```
Array
(
    [47] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 7
            [price] => 200.00
            [total] => 1400
            [thumb] => thumb.00
            [name] => name.00
            [model] => model.00
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 34
                    [1] => 56
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: с валютой я рабберусь - не заморачивайтесь на нее. в целом работает, есть ли вариант сделать автодобавление, всех значений, кроме которых мы изменяем, у меня просто  штук 20)

Comment: Они статичны? Т.е. у нас тут все три переменные (quantity, price, total) не статичны - они используются для вычислений или вычисляются. А другие переменные? Что за они?
Приведите пример хотя бы одного товара со всеми переменными. Например всё для  [product_id] => 31

Comment: Да, используются для вычислений, это инфа идет в корзину. Читается плохо, Вот 31 [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 31
            [cart_id] => 119
            [thumb] => http://shoes.loc/image/cache/catalog/1234-100x100.jpg
            [name] => Name 9
            [model] => Product 4
            [recurring] => 
            [quantity] => 5
            [price] => $100.00
            [total] => $500.00
            [href] => http://site.loc/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=31
        )

Comment: этот товар без дублей и по дефолту рисует правильно, я тоже продвигаюсь )) осталось $total отрисовать

Comment: @ultimatum а в чём причина того, что в исходном вашем массиве может появиться несколько раз один и тот же товар? Это ситуация, когда человек заказал одну обувь, а потом где-то ещё раз добавил её в корзину? Тогда почему сразу же не делать нормальный массив? Изначально? Ну ладно. Вопрос в другом. ИД товара - это действительно уникальный ИД? Т.е., например, у нас есть сапоги с ИД 32 но в разных цветовых вариантах. И каждый цвет стоит по разному? Или такая ситуация исключена?

Comment: ID уникальны. все дело в размерах, каждый размер отдельная запись - это переделывать лучше не стоит. Цветов у нас нет, только размеры, они в $product['option'], я  его убрал, т.к. в этом случае нам размеры не нужны, только кол-во цена и тотал листаем, остальное все остается дефолтное.

Comment: @ultimatum посмотрите, я дополнил свой ответ новым кодом. Как насчёт такого? Или я как-то не так понял всё это дело?

Comment: Огонь! Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @ultimatum обращайтесь) буду благодарен за + к ответам.

Comment: все уже сделал!)

Comment: @ultimatum поздравляю)

Comment: буду благодарен за + к вопросам тоже!)

Comment: @ultimatum к сожалению я не могу сделать этого - слишком мало очков репутации для этого. Да и вы же уже решили всё, нет?

Comment: @ n.osennij да все в порядке. от 15 уже можно!) еще раз Thank a lot of

Comment: @ultimatum успехов. не за что.

Comment: @ n.osennij взаимно!

Comment: @ultimatum Держите. Если у вас проблемы, могу всё сделать - договоримся.

Comment: @ n.osennij Благодарю за предложение. Но хочу разобраться сам, в этом весь смысл! Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужен уникальный результат, может так?

```
<?php
$uniqid = array();
$uniqArray = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($products as $val) {
if(!in_array($val['product_id'],$uniqid)){
array_push($uniqArray,$val);
$count++;
}
}
print_r($uniqArray);
print_r($count);

?>
```

Comment: выдает пустой массив...., в идеале можно и total, но это не обязательно

Comment: @ultimatum Просто можно вставить счётчик в цикл и получить количество массива... то что результат пустой, проверьте входящий массив, там точно такое строение которое вы показали ?

Comment: Вообще тут скорее не `isset`, a `in_array` и не `$count++`, a `$count+= $val['quantity'];`

Comment: упс, сори, автоматом вставил )) щас поправлю

Comment: ultimatum вам количество записей в массиве надо или колличество продуктов? как верно заметил @users, но мне показалось что количество массива вам надо получить.. ))

Comment: @Arsen желаемый результат добавил в вопрос

Comment: входящий остался без изменений

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
function getArray($products) {
    $products_new = [];
    foreach($products as $key => $val) {
        if(!isset($products_new[$val['product_id']])) {
            $products_new[$val['product_id']]["quantity"] = $val['quantity'];
            $products_new[$val['product_id']]["price"] = $val['price'];
        } else {
            $products_new[$val['product_id']]["quantity"] += $val['quantity'];
        }
        $products_new[$val['product_id']]["total"] = $val['total'] * $products_new[$val['product_id']]["quantity"];
    }
    return $products_new;
}

print_r(getArray($products));
```

Ну и привидения к старому виду (если это нужно):

```
function getOldArray($products_new){
    $products = [];
    foreach($products_new as $key => $val) {
        $products[] = [
            "product_id" => $key,
            "quantity" => $val['quantity'],
            "price" => $val['price'],
            "total" => $val['total'],
        ];
    }
    return $products;
}

print_r(getOldArray(getArray($products)));
```

Comment: Близко но не совсем... Array(
    [0] => 31
    [1] => 47
    [2] => 50
)

Comment: @ultimatum  я как понял нужна сумма `quantuty` по определенному `product_id`?

Comment: да! я добавил ожидаемый результат в ответ. Спасибо)